# Does anyone know of a good guide to get Ninject 2 working in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm struggling with the documentation to figure out exactly what I need to. The documentation (to my understanding) is for 1.5 anyway.

**N.B:** I don't want to extend NinjectHttpApplication

I've configured it to use the **NinejctControllerFactory** in **Application_Start()** but I get a null reference exception on the **KernelContainer.Kernel** when it tries to create a controller. Where do I configure the Kernel if I'm not extending NinjectHttpApplication?

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to extend NinjectHttpApplication?

Comment: I'm already extending another custom HttpApplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post.  It should help clarify the process you need to perform on how to configure the kernel.

http://www.kevinrohrbaugh.com/blog/2009/8/7/using-ninject-2-with-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: This is still based on deriving from NinjectHttpApplication.

Comment: When he says extend, does he mean derive/inherit?

Answer (score 5):

Since you're already extending another HttpApplication-derived class, my thoughts are to just copy the relevant source code from the **NinjectHttpApplication** class into your extended HttpApplication class.  Rather than cut and paste it, just look at the [source](http://github.com/enkari/ninject.web.mvc/blob/635e6d2bb74dd9e60fb0115ddad9929d5672108c/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectHttpApplication.cs) for **NinjectHttpApplication** in the Ninject2 Ninject.Web.Mvc extension project [here](http://github.com/enkari/ninject.web.mvc/blob/635e6d2bb74dd9e60fb0115ddad9929d5672108c/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectHttpApplication.cs).

I would specifically copy the stuff in **Application_Start()** and **Application_Stop()** methods. The other methods for registering controllers are nice, but you can register your controllers however you wish.  You'll note in the **Application_Start()**, the kernel is created by calling the pure virtual function **CreateKernel()** -- you can simply create your kernel inline right there.  Additionally, note the presence of the Kernel property on the **NinjectHttpApplication** class -- I'd copy that into your own class as well.  It would appear the intent here is that the HttpApplication-derived class effectively serves as the KernelContainer.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this to see if it works, though I will be shortly.  I've used Ninject 1.x in a web project and intend to upgrade to Ninject 2 in the near future; however, I'll probably be able to derive directly from NinjectHtppApplication.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Not being able to derive from NinjectHttpApplication isn't a big deal. It's not doing too much, it's very convenient though. Peter Meyer's suggestion is the way to go. Just check out the source [here](http://github.com/enkari/ninject.web.mvc/blob/ac9e51a89465003dcfff5d5aacc2844f3a6ee9ca/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectHttpApplication.cs). You will have to inherit from IHaveKernel though.

Answer (score 0):

You still should paste the code you have so people can see where you might have gone wrong.

I think this code should be placed in your Application_Start:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(NinjectControllerFactory));
KernelContainer.Kernel = new StandardKernel(
    new AutoControllerModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
);
```

Comment: I've pretty much given my code in that all I have so far is setting the controller factory. It didn't seem too worth it for one line! Also, this is for v1 of Ninject. I am interested in v2.

Comment: I don't actually see any code, or any detailed stacktrace or anything else.  The solution seems obvious so I want to make sure you're at least doing the obvious.  I missed the ninject 2 part (only saw 1.5 inthe body), so I've updated my answer with what I think is right for Ninject 2.