# Created a class that inherits from NinjectModule, where to load now?

Tags: ninject

After creating a class that inherits from NinjectModule, and overriding the Load() method with all my binding calls, where do I setup ninject in my asp.net web application? (MVC)

Is it a httpmodule that I have to create? global.asax?

Comment: NB for MVC 3 and later, this has been superseded by Ninject.MVC3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE NB see comment on question - this only makes sense for MVC if using a very old Ninject (2 or earlier) and a very old MVC (2 or earlier)

---

There's a `NinjectHttpApplication` you derive from which auto-injects pages.

See [Does anyone know of a good guide to get Ninject 2 working in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962690/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-guide-to-get-ninject-2-working-in-asp-net-mvc)